# How to combine two components Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have one component which is a button, and one for html. I need to get the response from the button in the html component where i have `v-if` condition. If button click true append the html.

```
 <template>

    <button v-on:click="greet">Greet</button>

</template>

    <script>
        export default {
    
            data () {
                return {
                    toggle: false,
                }
            },
    
            mounted() {
                console.log('Add more componente mounted.')
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Html component:

```
<template>

        <div v-show='toggle' class="bg-white">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                    ....
                    .....
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</template>

    <script>
        export default {
    
            data () {
                return {
                    toggle: true
                }
            },
    
            mounted() {
                console.log('Add more componente mounted.')
            }
        }
    </script>
```

How to get/pass and use the button response in the html component, **toggle: false,**

Comment: i understand that you have a parent component and child one which is a button and you want to send event to the parent from your button component?

Comment: What is your folder structure? If `v-if` component is a child of html component, create a function and pass as prop. Otherwise if they got a common parent, handle switching of variable used in if condition there. 

BTW, I recommend to use a state management solution such as Vuex to futureproof the project.

Comment: Why should  i use Vuex, what are the benefits? Can you show me an example how to make child and parent components and pass the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can exchange data between a parent component and child one using `props` to send data from parent to child and `this.$emit` event to send data from child to parent.

the child button component

```js
<template>
        <button v-on:click="greet">Greet</button>
 </template>
 <script>
            export default {
                props:[toggle:{type:boolean,default:false}]
                data () {
                    return {}        
                },
                methods:{
                greet(){
                this.$emit("btn-click");
                }
                }
                ,
                mounted() {
                    console.log('Add more componente mounted.')
                }
            }
</script>
```

and the parent html component

```js
<template>

        <div v-show='toggle' class="bg-white">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                  <your-btn :toggle="toggle" v-on:btn-click="greetFromBtn"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</template>

    <script>
    import yourBtn from 'pathToYourBtnComponent/yourBtn'
        export default {

            data () {
                return {
                    toggle: true
                }
            },
            components:{
            yourBtn
            },
            methods:{
            greetFromBtn(){
            
            }
            },

            mounted() {
                console.log('Add more componente mounted.')
            }
        }
    </script>
```